# Summing multiple columns using a regular expression to select which columns to sum

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to perform the following:"

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'A1':[1,1,1,1],
              'A2':[1,2,2,1],
              'A3':[1,1,1,1],
              'B1':[1,1,1,1],
              'B2':[pd.NA, 1,1,1]})
result = pd.DataFrame({'A': test.filter(regex='A').sum(axis=1),
 'B': test.filter(regex='B').sum(axis=1)})
```

I was wondering whether there is a better method to do this, when we have more columns and more "regex"-matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dict comprehension instead multiple repeat code like:

```
L = ['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame({x: test.filter(regex=x).sum(axis=1) for x in L})
```

Or if possible simplify solution by select only first letters use:

```
df = test.groupby(lambda x: x[0], axis=1).sum()
print (df)
   A    B
0  3  1.0
1  4  2.0
2  4  2.0
3  3  2.0
```

If regexes should ne joined by `|` and gt all columns substrings use:

```
vals = test.columns.str.extract('(A|B)', expand=False)
print (vals)
Index(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], dtype='object')

df = test.groupby(vals, axis=1).sum()
print (df)
   A    B
0  3  1.0
1  4  2.0
2  4  2.0
3  3  2.0
```

Comment: Is it possible to generalise the answer by not only selecting the first letter, but a general regex expression?

Comment: @Snowflake - I think not, need first solution

Comment: @Snowflake - added one idea, but it is not general.